# Reading one byte by File IO operation

Tags: java, io

the read method of FileInputStream will read 1 byte everytime, but who it is reading a character in a file, as the character size in java is (16 bit-2 Bytes). Is it because read method is native it will convert to 8-bits?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "who it is reading a character in a file"? Note that just because the internal representation of a char in Java is 16 bits doesn't mean that it's always 16 bits in binary encoded representation. Also note that FileInputStream is about reading *bytes*, not *characters*.

Comment: If you want to read characters, you can use [Reader.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read())

Comment: Files only contain a stream of bytes.  You can combine these into chars, int, long, double or any larger type, but how you do this is really up to you. Note: when encoded a `char` can use 1, 2 or 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The `read` method of `FileInputStream` reader returns an `int` (equivalent to a `byte`), not a character. It's your responsibility to transform the result into a character.

As the javadoc of `FileInputStream` suggest: "for reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader".

The number of bytes to encode a character depends on the encoding of the file. For example, if the file is encoded with ASCII, each byte is a character, but if your file is encoded in UTF-8, a character is 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes.

If you want more information about encoding, I would suggest reading the following article : [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).